IOS flutter app is not running after updating the Xcode and mac os
Recently I updates the Xcode to 16.0, flutter to 3.24.3 and also mac to 15.0.
After that I updates all the packages of used libraries to latest version using the command flutter pub upgrade --major-versions.
after that flutter clean and flutter pub get is executed.
After all of these steps, android app is working fine but the IOS app gives some error while running.
error:
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Method does not override any method from its superclass
/Users/aibelindia/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:1225:25

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Ambiguous use of 'evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)'
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:876:20

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Ambiguous use of 'evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)'
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:879:16

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Ambiguous use of 'evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)'
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:888:20

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Ambiguous use of 'evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)'
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:891:16

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Ambiguous use of 'evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)'
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:1121:25

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Ambiguous use of 'evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)'
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:1621:8

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Ambiguous use of 'evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)'
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:2618:21

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Ambiguous use of 'evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)'
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:2833:17

Anyone have a solution for this?

Short Answer
update flutter_inappwebview version to 6.1.0 to fix this issue
Details
Walking you through the process so that similar issues can be resolved via you in future also.
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Method does not override any method from its superclass
/Users/aibelindia/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:1225:25

the first line tells that it's not overriding any function from superclass, means the signature is changed. Intent here is to override the correct method.
Go to flutter_inappwebview github to check their issues, if anyone has already raised it. Fortunately it's already been raised and resolved. You can go through this issue thread for more details.
The library's author release 6.1.0 which fixes this.

However, I could not use that package in the pub.yaml file.

then you can go the manual route using this fix. PS: might be a bit risky

thanks for the response bro, but I cant take any risk on this..

Downgrading Xcode to 15.x seems to be the only viable option as of now.
